# Tangled database design for food delivery app

Tags: laravel, eloquent, database-design

I'm designing the database for a food delivery app. There are special kind of products:

Product examples:

- Kebab (price is fixed)
- Pizza Margherita - (price is dynamic)
- Pizza Half-Half - (price is dynamic - there are two products combined into one)

Selections within product:

- Each product can have selections like sizes and sauces.
- Size selection changes the product price.
- Sauces selection depends on size selection. For small size you have 1 sauce, for medium 2 sauces and so on. You can chose extra sauces paying extra.

What are your thoughts about this? Perhaps there is something open-source addressing this. I need to keep the Laravel style for functionalities like validations, model creations and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is the database structure. What I do in this cases is write my ideas in a piece of paper, until they get better and better. It helps.

Something quick I can recommend, you can obviously change it a bit.

- Products table: id, name, description(nullable)
- Product sizes table: id, size
- Product sizes pivot table: product_id, size_id
- Product prices table: id, product_id, size_id, price
- Sauces table: id, sauce_name, sauce_price
- Product sauces pivot table: product_id, sauce_id

If someone orders a Pizza Margherita, you just calculate it's price directly based on it's size from the prices table.

If someone lets say orders Half Pizza Margherita and half Pepperoni with 3 extra sauces you can do this:
(Margherita price / 2) + (Pepperoni price / 2) + (extra sauce price + extra sauce price + extra sauce price) = total price.

Comment: Nice one. What do you think about 3 issues?

1. The number of Sauces you can get is limited: for each size you get a number of sauces(these are free). You can get extra sauces.. let's say 2 more for extra money. Where in the database should I store these values?

2. Not all the Pizzas are available for Half-Half. Again.. I have to store these values somewhere.

3. Not all the Sizes are available for Half-Half

Those values.. should be editable from an admin panel

Comment: for the half-half, you can add another column which will be boolean, and depending on the size, you set it true or false from the admin area. Regarding the sauces, you can do a check in the backend, if they ordered more than the free ones. Again max number of free sauces you can store in an integer column or just set it up in a model constant.

Comment: Again I recommend putting all your ideas into a piece of paper, and combine them until you check all the ticks. This is just a simple, fast solution from me, but for sure there can be room for improvement.